# PPTP VPN Windows Server 2008 Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, pptp

I have a few questions that I hope that you guys can answer, so here goes.

I am running Windows Server 2008 enterprise in my HOME network inside of vmware workstation.  I am running this on my home network to setup a PPTP VPN connection at home.  I have correctly setup everything I needed to make it work, including opening all the ports, 1723 and 43 (GRE).  I am able to connect just fine, but when I connect I dont have internet unless I uncheck use remote gateway.  The thing is, I want to use the remote gateway to route all my traffic through that connection.  Can someone tell me why this isnt working and how to get it to work.  When I have remote gateway checked, and I do an ipconfig I dont get a remote gateway for the VPN connection, its 0.0.0.0 when id assume if connected properly should be 192.168.1.254 (my ATT Router).

Also, if I cant get the remote gateway issue to work, and I have to uncheck that box to get internet, does this mean my VPN session is no longer encrypted? I am fully aware the PPTP VPN is the weakest VPN encryption out there but still having that extra layer of security when im on an unsecure wifi connection makes me feel a bit better.  Thank you for all your help in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but home networking questions are explicitly off-topic on Server Fault per our [FAQ].  Your problem sounds like you do not have a gateway/router configured at the remote end of the tunnel to handle your traffic -- you'll need to set that up (or use split tunneling) in order to maintain internet access when connected to the VPN.

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to advise something without clean understanding of the network scheme. But I think you just need to enable NAT on server's external interface in order to make it work.