# Exchange 2010 Setup Questions

Tags: exchange-2010

Im starting to learn Exchange on my own, kind of a side project.  I recently purchased 2 domains from godaddy to play around with it.  The 2 domains that I own are digthelongball.com and chitownfantasy.com

I dont really want to call this is an issue but more of someone being able to either give me instructions how to host my exchange email on my server at home or give me step by step instructions.

Currently, I have a server up running Server 2008 R2 with exchange 2010 on it.  I havent updated it yet, so it has no service packs or anything yet.  As I stated above, I currently have 2 domains hosted by godaddy.  The one im trying to setup email with is digthelongball.com

Currently, inside my godaddy dns I have an mx record "@ email.digthelongball.com" and then an A record that has email.digthelongball.com pointing to my home external IP which is hosted by ATT Uverse.

After this is where im completely confused. I essentially have exchange setup to send email externally by reading a few articles and what not but my DNS setup isnt complete.  Where im confused I guess is what do I add to the internal DNS on my home server.  And is my godaddy DNS properly configured?

Also, I cannot access my OWA from the outside, could you guys please help me get that accessible from the outside as well?  I really appreciate all the help.  I hope this is enough information, if its not I will be more than happy to provide more.

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: You've already had [one home related question closed](http://serverfault.com/questions/448784/pptp-vpn-windows-server-2008-enterprise) as off topic, so you should know that this question is off topic too. But just in case you haven't read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) yet, I'd suggest you do so.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add anything to the internal DNS on your home server.

http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3adigthelongball.com&run=toolpage# shows your DNS is OK and SMTP connections to your server are at least partly working (firewall OK).

You need to configure Exchange to not drop the connection (follow the MXToolbox link and click the SMTP test link), I can't guess why it's doing that.

Configure Exchange to answer email for those two domains, add a recipient policy or add the email addresses to your user account. Sounds like you are nearly there.

Follow the Exchange 2010 Deployment Assistant: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/exdeploy2010/default%28EXCHG.150%29.aspx and/or install checklist here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff805042%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx

> Also, I cannot access my OWA from the outside, could you guys please help me get that accessible from the outside as well?

For a start, your server is not answering on port 443 (HTTPS). Check your firewall / router / port forwarding settings. Then Windows firewall. Then IIS configuration - is it listening on port 443? Then Exchange Outlook Web Access configuration (does it work on the LAN?)

http://testexchangeconnectivity.com/ will do a more thorough job than any of us could, although it can't check OWA directly, if you can get Outlook Anywhere / Exchange Activesync connecting from it, then OWA will stand a good chance of working, too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will see what I can do to fix these issues.  For the OWA, dont I need to add a record to the godaddy DNS?  I have no record of mail.digthelongball.com anywhere, that is my OWA address.

Comment: If you have an SSL certificate for it, you will need a DNS entry for the SSL Certificate address so it works properly. But it should be accessible and workable using https:// IP /owa or https:// email.digthelongball.com /owa albeit with an SSL warning about a name mismatch. If you use self-signed SSL or are testing with the default certificate, it won't make much real difference. If you have a single SSL cert, then you will need an internal DNS A record for mail.digthelongball.com IP:internal IP. With a SAN certificate, you could put the server's hostname in for internal use. Lots of options!